# Clearing css floats with foundation 4 framework

Tags: css, css-float, zurb-foundation

I'm developing a website but i'm having a hard time with clearing the floats. I'm using the foundation 4 framework. When the .columns class is applied to an element it will float the elements left. When the browser is re-sized some of the elements become larger in height and forces the element below to push down to the next row.

I've tried adding clear:left to the elements but that pushes all of the elements to the left of the page. here's a screenshot of what's happening, http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/img/522621c34826e6-18306724

here's the url for this page, http://theinfluence.iamchrisbarnard.com/news/

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple large-6 overflowing the row and wrapping.

You need to surround each pair of large-6 in a row like the below jsbin.

If you do that the issue will be resolved.

http://jsbin.com/EcojoHE/1/